# Error in ReactJS setup in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to follow https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm inorder to setup reactJS in my device which has Ubuntu 16.04.

In the end i tried `npm start` but it results me following error

```
> reactjs@1.0.0 start /var/www/html/reactjs
> webpack-dev-server --hot

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "./" is not an absolute path!

npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! reactjs@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --hot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --hot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs reactjs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/reactjs/npm-debug.log
```

My **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "reactjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward error message ever.

You can't use relative path in output (I don't remember wheather it was possible in previous versions of webpack). [Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-path).

```
output: {
   path: require('path').resolve(__dirname, './path/to/build/folder'),
```

Comment: @RafinKarki Webpack configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Use **create-react-app** for creating new reactjs application.

Just delete your `node_modules` folder and reinstall your npm package with `npm install`.